# JavaScript - Hide a Div at startup (load)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, hide

I have a div in my php page that uses jQuery to hide it once the page has loaded. But is there a way to hide it from the very start of loadup?

The reason I ask is because for a brief second, you can see the div when the page is loading, and then hides when the page is fully loaded.

It looks unprofessional.

Just wondering if there is a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just set the css of the div to `display: none`?

Comment: I suggest you to pass this course: http://www.w3schools.com/css/, before submitting any question about css.

Comment: I suggest you don't. w3schools is wrong as often as it is right.

Comment: @pylover w3schools references and the contents are outdated and they don't keep their standards up-to-date. I recently learned it hard way and I suggest you either look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ or http://www.w3.org/

Comment: w3schools is enough for oliver

Comment: [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: @pylover wrote "w3schools is enough for Oliver"...you are basically saying that as Oliver is newish to coding, he can suffice with sources that are outdated and half incorrect?

Comment: +1 for a good question. That's right. 'It looks unprofessional.'

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use css style to hide the div.

```
#selector { display: none; }
```

or Use it like below,

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="blah" class="hidden"><!-- div content --></div>
```

and in jQuery

```
 $(function () {
     $('#blah').removeClass('hidden');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, although all the answers here were helpful. This one works fantastic. Thank you all

Comment: I would like to add that the div will stay hidden if javascript is disabled. You can use a class like .no-js (see Modernizr) to show it if that is the case. Especially useful for fade-in, slide-in etc. animations that start when the page is fully loaded.

Comment: You can also use the js method `toggleClass('hidden')` to easily toggle its visibility.

Answer (score 10):

I've had the same problem.

Use CSS to hide is not the best solution, because sometimes you want users without JS can see the div..
The cleanest solution is to hide the div with JQuery. But the div is visible about 0.5 seconde, which is problematic if the div is on the top of the page.

In these cases, I use an intermediate solution, without JQuery. This one works and is immediate :

`<script>document.write('<style>.js_hidden { display: none; }</style>');</script>`

`<div class="js_hidden">This div will be hidden for JS users, and visible for non JS users.</div>`

Of course, you can still add all the effects you want on the div, JQuery toggle() for example.
And you will get the best behaviour possible (imho) :

- for non JS users, the div is visible directly
- for JS users, the div is hidden and has toggle effect.

Comment: In my opinion that is the best answer. Although, I would rather use the .no-js class provided by Modernizr for a less messy approach.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without document.write?

Comment: To be fair, css solution is not always easily applicable. For example, when div is generated by third party module. So, hiding elements by JS as fast as possible (even without waiting for document ready)

Answer (score 9):

Barring the CSS solution. The fastest possible way is to hide it immediatly with a script.

```
<div id="hideme"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#hideme").hide();
</script>
```

In this case I would recommend the CSS solution by Vega. But if you need something more complex (like an animation) you can use this approach.

This has some complications (see comments below). If you want this piece of script to really run as fast as possible you can't use jQuery, use native JS only and defer loading of all other scripts.

Comment: Inline `script` tags will only create more mess to your HTML file.

Comment: He needs absolute speed, that goal justifies a little messy HTML. Be pragmatic, know when to break from the standard.

Comment: But I don't think jQuery has already loaded in... `$("hideme").hide();` might give you a `ReferenceError`...

Comment: It wont, (assuming jQuery is included in the header) it will run as soon as it is available. JavaScript is executed in-order meaning this script will be executed only after loading and executing all scripts before it.

Comment: Doesn't it need time to load? As it gets to the line, jQuery might not be fully loaded. (when using slow internet)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But this is still the fastest way to do it, given the limitations. If the jQuery source script is cached there is almost no delay of course.

Comment: This isn't the solution you would want. You could just skip the jQuery  framework and just use native JS and defer the load of all other scripts but that might give rise to other complications. But I suppose it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

Why not add "display: none;" to the divs style attribute?  Thats all JQuery's .hide() function does.

Comment: If you look at the OP you'll see the div needs to be hidden before jQuery is loaded.  That is what's causing the FOUC.  You have to use the CSS solution to ensure the div is hidden while jQuery is loading. using .hide() only works after jQuery is loaded.

Comment: @JimpP I think Moo is staying you should add it directly to the element like so <div style="display: none;">Hidden content</div> Hiding the element from the html from the very beginning. jQuery uses this css attribute in it's hide and show functions. I think this is a good answer, but should be more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

This method I've used a lot, not sure if it is a very good way but it works fine for my needs.

```
<html>
<head>  
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="HiddenStuff1" style="display:none">
    CONTENT TO HIDE 1
    </div>
    <div id="HiddenStuff2" style="display:none">
    CONTENT TO HIDE 2
    </div>
    <div id="HiddenStuff3" style="display:none">
    CONTENT TO HIDE 3
    </div>
    <input id="YOUR ID" title="HIDDEN STUFF 1" type=button name=type value='HIDDEN STUFF 1' onclick="setVisibility('HiddenStuff1', 'inline');setVisibility('HiddenStuff2', 'none');setVisibility('HiddenStuff3', 'none');";>
    <input id="YOUR ID" title="HIDDEN STUFF 2" type=button name=type value='HIDDEN STUFF 2' onclick="setVisibility('HiddenStuff1', 'none');setVisibility('HiddenStuff2', 'inline');setVisibility('HiddenStuff3', 'none');";>
    <input id="YOUR ID" title="HIDDEN STUFF 3" type=button name=type value='HIDDEN STUFF 3' onclick="setVisibility('HiddenStuff1', 'none');setVisibility('HiddenStuff2', 'none');setVisibility('HiddenStuff3', 'inline');";>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does it work? What changes did you make? Answers that tackle the question in this manner help the reader understand their own problem better

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you can just set display:none for the element in a CSS file or in a style attribute

```
#div { display:none; }
<div id="div"></div>



<div style="display:none"></div>
```

or having the js just after the div might be fast enough too, but not as clean