# removeClass doesn't undo CSS effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle, removeclass

I have designed a script to show two different streams of realizations of random variables. Once the streams have been fully displayed, I would like to display two previously hidden buttons (which allows the user to select which stream had the higher average).

My current method is to use CSS to hide the buttons, and removeClass to undo the effects of CSS at the required time, as recommended in [JavaScript - Hide a Div at startup (load)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148660/javascript-hide-a-div-at-startup-load).

http://jsfiddle.net/jshyaL57/1/

However, I have encountered two issues:

1. The removeClass isn't working as I intended it to:

   ```
   $("#button_form").removeClass("hidden");
   $("#stream1button").removeClass("hidden");
   $("#stream2button").removeClass("hidden");
   ```

Do you know a way around this? I've tried the methods recommended in several of the related questions, but they don't work.

2. The Gaussian random variables run when you click "Push me to start!" in my web browser, but don't run in JSfiddle when I copy and paste the code. Why might that be the case?

Comment: The problem you have is the fiddle is not set up right. code is wrapped in document ready and you call the function as a global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loaded javascript on dom ready,you have to give it in head or body section.
I updated fiddle and changed the option to load javascript to body.
Here is the updated fiddle [JSFIddle][1]

http://jsfiddle.net/jshyaL57/2/

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Thanks! For the uninitiated, here's how to do so in actual HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036969/nowrap-condition-in-html-head-and-body