# hide a paragraph that is already showing page load when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot get my head around how to do this, but I was wondering how I would hide text that is showing on page load when a button is clicked.

This is what I currently have:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $p = $('p#menu_title');
   $("input#save_first_prod").click(function() {
      $p.css('visibility', 'hidden');
   });
});
```

```html
<div id="red_head">
   <p id="menu_title" onclick="hideText('text1')" > Add your first menu item</p>
</div>
<form name="first_prod" id="first_prod" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="testing.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" >               
   <input type="Submit" id="save_first_prod" name="save_first_prod" value=" + ADD"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Hide a Div at startup (load)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148660/javascript-hide-a-div-at-startup-load)

Comment: You are binding a click event to a submit button. After you pressing the button the page will be reloaded/redirected.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy thank you. I should have explained that i am going to do more with the page, just wanted to get this sorted first

Comment: @nhouser9 it is not the same question. I want to hide a paragraph with is viewable when the page loads, then hide at the paragraph at a later date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:none;` instead of `visibility`

Change `$p.css('visibility', 'hidden');` to `$p.css('display', 'none');`

This works fine for me

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var $p = $('p#menu_title');
$("input#save_first_prod").click(function() {
    $p.css('display', 'none');

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red_head">
                <p id="menu_title" onclick="hideText('text1')" > Add your first menu item</p>
            </div>

 <form name="first_prod" id="first_prod" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="testing.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" >               
<input type="Submit" id="save_first_prod" name="save_first_prod" value=" + ADD"> 

            </form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Fast snail

Comment: It works perfectly in the example, but not in my browser. Do you mind if i ask what browser you are using

Comment: Firefox and I tested to my own laptop.@Monroe

Comment: If it works, you should accept the answer so that other people can be benefited from it. Thank you.@Monroe

Comment: You might have miss `jquery` file.You can use this Fiddle [example][1] 


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/sud0rbsj/

Comment: No I am asking you to check that your `Jquery` file included correctly or not.If your `Jquery` file not added then it will not work.Check your `Jquery` path and debug with console.

Comment: You can try this following two options  
1. change `$("input#save_first_prod")` to `$("#save_first_prod")`  
2.  

    $("input#save_first_prod").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $p.css('display', 'none');
    });

Comment: Number 2 ordered perfectly.